# Unsupported target for indexed assignment

Tags: python, typing, mypy

Function runs perfectly, but I am getting error with mypy:

> Unsupported target for indexed assignment

Here is my code:

```
def function(image: List[str], start: Tuple[int]):
    if image[start[0]][start[1]] == "*":
        return
    else:
        image[start[0]][start[1]] = "*"
        if start[0] > 0:
            function(image, [start[0]-1, start[1]])
        if start[0] < len(image) - 1:
            function(image, [start[0]+1, start[1]])
        if start[1] > 0:
            function(image, [start[0], start[1]-1])
        if start[1] < len(image) - 1:
            function(image, [start[0], start[1]+1])
```

The mistake is in line:

```
image[start[0]][start[1]] = "*"
```

image = ["*", "."]
start = (1, 1) - tuple contains coordinates.

Comment: With ``image: List[str]``, ``image[start[0]]`` is just a ``str``. Strings are immutable, their elements cannot be assigned to.

Comment: yes,  because `image[start[0]][start[1]] = "*"` does not support indexed assignment if `image: List[str]`. What are you *actually* passing to your function?

Comment: @MV912HB please provide an actual example in the question itself.

Comment: Can you please clarify how this code is supposed to work? The example input of ``image = ["*", "."]``, ``start = (1, 1)`` fails in the first line of the function, because it tries to access the second item of ``"*"`` – which does not exist. Is ``image`` actually supposed to be a two-dimensional list, as in ``function([['*', "*"], ["*", "*"]], (1, 1))``?

Comment: A two-dimensional list is ``List[List[str]]``, not ``List[str]``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks, you helped me a lot! I did not pay attention. I am new to python, tried coding 6 weeks ago for the very first time. And correct type for image is Tuple[int, int].

Answer (score 4):

```
self._balances:Mapping[str,Optional[float]]
```

If anyone comes here because of using `Mapping`, use `MutableMapping` instead, because you can only assign values to a mutable object

```
self._balances:MutableMapping[str,Optional[float]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
The correct types are:

```
image: List[List[str]], start: Tuple[int, int]
```